# SSH server: What's more secure, pub key auth or Google Authenticator time-based auth?

Tags: ssh, multi-factor

I'm curious which would be more secure, pub key authentication or 2-factor auth via Google Authenticator. Apparently I can't use both. If I have pub key authentication, the Google Auth PAM module doesn't ask me for a verification code. But if someone tries to log in with a regular password, it does. So it seems it's either-or.

Answer (score 3):

It depends, what are you more concerned about?  Someone being able to steal your private key, or someone stealing your TOTP seeds?  That'll determine which is more likely to be compromised.

Alternatively, if your version of SSHD is new enough, you can use the [`AuthenticationMethods`](http://lwn.net/Articles/544640/) option in `sshd_config` to require both, with something like `publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam`.  This will require both a functional pubkey and the full PAM stack.

An attacker who passively observes traffic should not be able to learn anything about TOTP traffic, as its encapsulated in the SSH connection, and the SSH public key is computationally infeasible to factor for modern key lengths (ECDSA, or RSA >= 2048).

Comment: Nope, running sshd 6.0. And I suppose that's my question: which is easier to be compromised, a private key or TOTP seeds?

Comment: I guess the question is, then, for someone sniffing packets, which is harder to crack: ssh pub key auth, or TOTP? Because my private key is definitely secure on my phone and desktop computer.

Answer (score 3):

Public key pair. As you have more control over exactly security you want, how you use it and how you store it.

That said, security doesn't exist if it isn't used or usable. The Google Authenticator has added quick, strong security to use cases that previously had none. The hassle of handling and distributing your key pairs may very well end up with you not using them and just reverting to one-factor vanilla passwords.

Answer (score 1):

In most scenarios **Google Authenticator** is more secure.

The two techniques have slightly different risk profiles, and it depends how your phone and laptop are configured. Lets assume you're following security best practice:

- Both laptop and phone are encrypted with a strong password.
- The devices have all security updates, the laptop has firewall and anti-virus, and the phone isn't jailbroken.
- When you login you always verify the public key of the server.

If you do follow all this, your greatest risk is malware on the laptop. Despite following best practice, malware often still can infect laptops. Malware on smart phones is possible, but less common, so your phone is safer than your laptop. And that's why Google Authenticator is the more secure option.

Public key authentication has some advantages. For example, if you inadvertently connect to a malicious server, that server cannot impersonate you. However, with Google Authenticator, they get your code, and have up to 30 seconds to login to the real server. But if you always verify the server's public key, this doesn't matter.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "verify the public key of the server"?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack - when you connect to the server, you verify that the public key is correct. Most SSH clients do this automatically on second connections, but you must do it manually the first time.

Comment: I never knew about this. How exactly do I verify it? I ssh into my-server, and then..?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack - this is basic ssh usage. You will find instructions online

Comment: Are you talking about using `ssh-keygen -l -f` to visually compare the fingerprints of the client's private key and the server's copy of the public key?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack - similar, I'm talking about verifying the server's key. Google for "verify server ssh key" gives [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-essentials-checking-a-server%E2%80%99s-ssh-host-fingerprint-with-the-web-console)

Comment: Ah, learn something new every day! I'm familiar with the ssh prompt upon first connection to a server, I just never knew I could verify the server fingerprint once I logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on the environment and the users you're operating with.

A large IT organisation where end users can't be expected to take adequate precautions with a private key? Probably best to use Google Authenticator and passwords.

Just you and your personal server, where the private key never leaves the box it was generated on, has a strong password on the key, and you're confident in your ability to keep that box secure, patched, etc.? Public key authentication (ensuring that you turn off password authentication) is may be better in that case.

You'll need to assess the situation, environment and your users to make an informed decision about what's going to work for you or for your organisation.

Answer (score -1):

What a great question to show the weakness of shared secrets.

If you have less than a handful of servers, the google authenticator pam module  will be fine. However, since it is based on shared secrets, each server should have it's secret and thus a listing on the token.  If you use the same secret across servers, you risk  catastrophic failure across all the servers.

Both suffer from operational security concerns - how will you disable users and manage keys?  Also, if you plan on providing two-factor auth for other services, such as a VPN, neither of these is likely to work, so you will end up having multiple two-factor solutions. Here's a post I did on issues an enterprise might have with google auth for ssh: https://www.wikidsystems.com/WiKIDBlog/5-issues-enterprises-should-consider-before-using-google-authenticator-for-ssh

Comment: You should disclose that you are the CEO of a company offering a competing  2FA solution in this post, not in your profile. Downvoted.

Comment: I have done that sometimes, but not every time.  Fair enough, but my arguments apply for any 2FA solution vs google auth, which the  google auth pam creators are not suitable for wide-scale deployment.